# Is it possible to create dialog using android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, dialog, searchview

I am trying to create a dialog containing android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.  I have used the following layout XML in a regular Activity successfully, but cannot seem to get it to work in a dialog:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to use this same layout XML in a dialog. When I display the dialog, it gives the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating 
class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) at 
com.my.company.activity.MyActivity.selectReference(MyActivity.java:660) at 
com.my.company.activity.MyActivity$4.onClick(MyActivity.java:318) at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) at 
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105) at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586) ... 18 more Caused by: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class <unknown> at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606) at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) at 
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:262) ... 21 more Caused by: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at 
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586) ... 28 more Caused by: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): 
TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01005f a=-1} at 
android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1897) at 
android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) at android.widget.ImageView.
<init>(ImageView.java:119) at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109) ... 31 more
```

I do not want to use the ActionBar in the dialog, but IF this is the ONLY way to use the support SearchView, then how would I implement the onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected() methods in the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add an ActionBarTheme style to my activity in the manifest (i.e. android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme")! It all works!